# Making a cassette tape using itunes or mp3

Tags: audio, itunes, mp3, recording, cassette

I have watched videos about how to do this, read about it as well. I have headphone input cable which ends with two RCA cables. I insert this on the computer headphone and lineout (EXT) outlets on the cassette deck, set the player to EXT whereby I can hear my MP3's playing but when 
pressing record on the Cassette player then after listening, I get nothing, simple silence as though nothing has taken place. Any suggestions?

FYI: Stereo System is a Technics RSHD505
thank you

Comment: "I can hear my MP3's playing " from which device?

Comment: Try a stereo jack from headphones of PC into mic input in cassette recorder (if one present). Check cable isn't dead

Comment: you want **line in** on the deck.

Answer (score 3):

If you can *definitely* hear it from the cassette recorder with Rec/Pause, then the recorder is receiving the signal.

If you hear it from anywhere else, that doesn't count.

Most cassette recorders will have a volume indicator for input signal strength, as a guide. If it doesn't then your ***only*** test is if you can hear the throughput in Rec/Pause.

If all the above checks are correct & it still does not record, then suspect a faulty recorder.